# One Primary key map to multiple table as foreign key EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have one table API which has two files key and url. Key is primary key. Another table API_Action which has APIKey(FK) and ActionKey(String). APIKey is  PrimaryKey of API table and ActionKey is primary key. I have another table Permission which have columns like APIKey(FK), Name, Description, Key. APIKey is Primary key of API table.

I want to store the data using entityFramework core. But it gives me error.

```
<code>
public class API
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string ServiceUri { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Action> Actions { get; set; } = new List<Action>();
   public virtual List<PermissionType> PermissionTypes { get; set; } = new List<PermissionType>();
}
public class Action
{
   public string ActionKey { get; set; }
   public string APIKey { get; set; }
   public virtual API API { get; set; }
}
public class PermissionType
{
   public string APIKey { get; set; }
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public virtual API API { get; set; } 
}
</code>
```

I defined relation using FluentAPI.

```
<code>
modelBuilder
.Entity<Models.System.API>(b => b.ToTable("tbl_System_API").HasKey(o => o.Key))
            .Entity<Models.System.Action>(b => b.ToTable("tbl_System_API_Action").HasKey(o => new { o.ActionKey, o.APIKey }))
            .Entity<Models.System.Action>(b => b.ToTable("tbl_System_API_Action").HasOne(o => o.API).WithMany(o => o.Actions).HasForeignKey(o => o.APIKey))
.Entity<PermissionType>(b => b.ToTable("tbl_System_PermissionType").HasKey(o => o.Key))
            .Entity<PermissionType>(b => b.ToTable("tbl_System_PermissionType").HasOne(o => o.API).WithMany(o => o.PermissionTypes).HasForeignKey(o => o.APIKey))
</code>
```

At the time of Saving I am using

```
<code>
foreach (var api in apis)
{
   var actionss = actions.Where(o => o.APIKey == api.Key).ToList();
   api.Actions.AddRange(actionss);
}
foreach (var api in apis)
{
   var permissionTypess = permissionTypes.Where(o => o.APIKey == api.Key).ToList();
   api.PermissionTypes.AddRange(permissionTypess);
}

dataContext.APIs.AddRange(apis);
dataContext.Save();
</code>
```

I am getting below error.
The instance of entity type 'PermissionType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'APIKey'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I want to store parent table and child tables together with FK relation.

So API table should have values and Action and PermissionType tables should be filled with FK of API table and other fields.

Comment: The PK of `PermissionType` looks wrong. Are you sure it is `APIKey` and not other field or composite? If it really is `APIKey`, then it should be configured as one-to-one, not one-to-many.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. PrimaryKey in permission table is "Key".